# Node.js / Grunt export log to file

Tags: node.js, logging, gruntjs

Is there any way of exporting the console log of your Grunt build to a *.txt file?
I can run grunt in console with the >> thingy to export to file, like so:

```
grunt >> log.txt
```

But it does not log to console, only to file.
And I'd like a module/task to do it for me after the build has finished.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not actually grunt or node.js question. You need to use piping to [tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)).

```
grunt | tee log.txt
```

Or if you're using windows cmd:

```
grunt > log.txt | type log.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I also stated that I would like for grunt at the end of the build, to save a log file.

Comment: Try to look at [logfile-grunt](https://www.npmjs.org/package/logfile-grunt) plugin.

Comment: So why the heck didn't that come up when I searched through npmjs?! Thanks raindev.

Comment: +1 up for this.
I had a related query on this, how to format the out put log file text, I am getting it with out new line, as a bulk of data.